# Serializing & deserializing unmanaged C# type as raw bytes between different hosts

Tags: c#, .net

My question in short:
Which constraints must be fulfilled so that an unmanaged types' raw bytes from machine A can safely be "deserialized" (cast back to the original type from raw bytes) on a different physical machine? Can this even ever be safely done in any setup?

In more detail - say I have the following (de)serialization functions:

```
private static Span<byte> Serialize<T>(T value) where T : unmanaged
{
    return MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref value, 1));
}

private static T Deserialize<T>(Span<byte> bytes) where T : unmanaged
{
    return MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, T>(bytes)[0];
}
```

A value may be serialized in one C# process/host, and then deserialized in another C# process on another physical machine.

For that to be safe, I'd think both machines must have the same endianness.
But now imagine a struct that fulfills the unmanaged constraint, but has `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]`. Surely, the CLR could have re-arranged the struct's fields differently on differnet machines? But maybe it's safe if both machines run on the same CLR version, or the same CLR binaries (as in, same version + same OS)?

So I wonder, what exactly - if possible at all - must be fulfilled for this to be safe to do?

---

A bit more context: I'm working on a distributed data/calculation framework. Serialization is one of the, if not the biggest overhead here - and having to transfer blittable types indeed very common. So this would be a very tempting optimisation to make.
And in fact, in reality, usually instances of these would run in a containerized environment, so it seems likely that there would be binary compatibility. It would be easy to implement some check and only enable fast-path serializability for these types if all participating nodes are, say, on exactly the same CLR.

However, this all does feel rather fragile, so I'm still reluctant to implement something like that unless I understand *exactly* and with certainty what requirements would need to be fulfilled

Comment: it *could* be possible, but you're into deep waters here and really depending on luck because everything (in almost literal sense) has to be the same. I think the best (and most trustworthy) way forward is make a serializable transport object yourself. Serialization across machines using unmanaged raw data is more like a Infinite Improbability Drive

Answer (score 1):

> I'd think both machines must have the same endianness

Yes, the endianess would have to be the same.

> But now imagine a struct that fulfills the unmanaged constraint, but has [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]

Relying on any specific behavior of `LayoutKind.Auto` seem  extremely foolish, since as you mention, it will likely depend on CLR version. I would not expect OS to have any influence, but I would expect the platform, i.e. x86-32, x86-64, ARM etc, to influence the layout.

You might be able to get away with `LayoutKind.Auto` if you can guarantee that the platform and CLR version to be identical. This might be fine within the same process, but in any other circumstance you  would take a huge risk. If the layout changes you are not guaranteed to get an error. You could just get mangled data, and you might not detect this before it has caused serious harm.

If you are storing data, or doing any kind of network communication, you should probably follow some established protocol instead of relying on the whims of the .net runtime. For example a binary serialization protocol like protobuf (.net).  While this will be slower, it should not produce significantly more data.

You could also just specify the layout explicitly, but this will can cause issues if you ever need to change the struct or layout.

Comment: Thanks @JonasH . I definitely agree on the fragility here - I've added a short comment above in my post why this may be useful to me, and why I think this *probably* would work in most real cases in my specific use case. But trying to get more certainty before deciding whether it's a sensible tradeoff to make

Comment: @Bogey If all parts are part of the same "system", and do not have to worry about third parties or stored data, then the risk might be small enough to be worth the performance, it really depend on your specific environment. You might consider sending a struct with known values as part of the connection process, to ensure that any errors that do occur are detectable.

Comment: That's a great idea. I reckon stuff might still erroneously slip through there (e.g. just because fields *could* be re-ordered doesn't mean that *will* be re-ordered for any specific sample struct used for such a test.. but maybe would for some different struct) - but either way, certainly a very good idea for a bit of extra safety!

Comment: @Bogey I do not think that there is any possibility for different layouts for the same struct within the same process. That would really complicate the CLR for very little benefit. So if one is transmitted successfully you can be confident that all will be.